# how to set a header when serving a static file

Tags: ruby, apache, http-headers

I want to host an ical file, but when serving it, I need to set the Content-type header to calendar and stuff

in php, I would just

```
<?php
  header ("Content-type: text/calendar")
?>
//calendar stuff proceeds
```

Can I do the same using ruby?
or can I somehow tell apache to set a different header when serving this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_headers.html)